# How to select objects with highest value of Property A, grouped by Property B?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable

For example, if I have an list of objects with the following properties

```
No  Grouper Sorter
1     X       3
2     X       2
3     X       1
4     Y       3
5     Y       2
6     Y       5
7     Z       4
```

I want the result to contain object no 3 (X with highest Sorter), no 5 (Y with highest sorter), and no 7 (Z with highest sorter, well there's no other choice here).

```
No  Grouper Sorter
3     X       1
5     Y       2
7     Z       4
```

How can I do this, e.g. using Linq? I also don't mind if there's a clean and simple solution without Linq.

Comment: Don't think this is a duplicate.

Comment: @Liam no it's not. I added my expected result, to clarify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x=>x.Grouper)
                .Select(x=>x.OrderBy(y=>y.Sorter).First())
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

So, you want to [group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384063.aspx) by the grouper, then for each group [order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383982.aspx) by the sorter and keep the [first](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx) result. Using the links you should be able to piece something together, ending up with something like below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Thing> things = new List<Thing>()
            {
                new Thing(){ No = 1, Grouper = 'X', Sorter = 3  },
                new Thing(){ No = 2, Grouper = 'X', Sorter = 2  },
                new Thing(){ No = 3, Grouper = 'X', Sorter = 1  },
                new Thing(){ No = 4, Grouper = 'Y', Sorter = 3  },
                new Thing(){ No = 5, Grouper = 'Y', Sorter = 2  },
                new Thing(){ No = 6, Grouper = 'Y', Sorter = 5  },
                new Thing(){ No = 7, Grouper = 'Z', Sorter = 4  }
            };

            var test = from thing in things
                       group thing by thing.Grouper into thingGroup
                       select thingGroup.OrderBy(tg => tg.Sorter).First();

            foreach (var thing in test)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(thing);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Thing
    {
        public int No { get; set; }
        public char Grouper { get; set; }
        public int Sorter { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("No: {0}, Grouper: {1}, Sorter: {2}",
                                 No, Grouper, Sorter);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Output:

```
No: 3, Grouper: X, Sorter: 1
No: 5, Grouper: Y, Sorter: 2
No: 7, Grouper: Z, Sorter: 4
```